# Square-root of $\iota\iota^\ast$, where $\iota$ is an isometric embedding between Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let $U$ and $H$ be Hilbert spaces and $\iota$ be an embedding of $U$ into $H$. Then, $$\pi x:=u\;\;\;\text{for }x\in H\text{ with }x=\iota u+y\text{ for some }u\in U\text{ and }y\in\left(\iota U\right)^\perp$$ is a well-defined mapping $H\to U$. If $\iota$ is an isometry, then $$\langle\iota u,x\rangle_H=\langle\iota u,\iota\left(\pi x\right)\rangle_H=\langle u,\pi x\rangle_U\;\;\;\text{for all }u\in U\text{ and }x\in H\;,$$ i.e. the adjoint of $\iota$ is given by $$\iota^\ast=\pi\;.$$

> Can we find a concrete representation of the square-root $Q^{1/2}$ of $Q:=\iota\iota^\ast$?

If that's not possible, can we find it, if $U\subseteq H$ and $\iota$ is the inclusion?

Comment: If $\iota$ is an isometry, then $Q:=\iota\iota^{*}$ is the projection
from $H$ onto $ran\left(\iota\right)$. So it seems that $Q=Q^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: @James What is $ran\left(\iota\right)$? Maybe the image $\iota(U)$? Can you prove your claim?

Comment: Yes, $ran(\iota)$ is the image.

Comment: @James By definition of $\pi$, the projection from $H$ onto $V:=\iota(U)$ is $\iota\pi=\iota\iota^\ast=Q$. That's clear to me. But how do you conclude that $Q=Q^{1/2}$?

Comment: Perhaps one way to check that is to square both sides. So $Q^{2}=Q$ as a projection; and $(Q^{\frac{1}{2}})^{2}=Q$.

Comment: @James Yeah, seems to be correct, cause $Q$ is nonnegative and symmetric.

Comment: @James What if $\iota$ is not an isometry between $U$ and $H$, but an isometry between $U$ and a subspace of $H$ (equipped with a different inner product)? Can we show a similar result? I've asked a [new question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818235/whats-the-effect-of-the-operator-iota-iota-ast-if-iota-is-an-embedding) for that. Maybe you can help there too.

Comment: 0xbadf00d I'm not quite sure what you meant. Seems that you are working on 'rigged Hilbert space', 'Gelfand triple', etc. I think you may find something useful in this book http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780792362081. Especially the example of pg 37.